# How to get a link on the deleted answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

If an answer is deleted on Programmers and the author wants to ask about the reason on MetaProgrammers, how can he do it? How can he reference something that doesn't exist? He can't edit it, either, it is unseen.

Comment: You ask on Meta.Programmers, not Meta.StackOverflow. This is where moderators of Programmers will most likely see the question and will be able to respond. If you have a link to the question (assuming it hasn't been deleted, in which case you already know why the answer was deleted), you should still be able to see the deleted answer (and get a link to it).

Comment: You'll find a "deleted recent answers" link at the bottom of your [profile's answers tab](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/44104/gangnus?tab=answers).

Comment: @YannisRizos - only applies to recent answers (ie. those posted recently). The post needs to be recent, not the deletion.

Comment: @Oded Ah, good to know.

Comment: @YannisRizos - that's why the phrasing is that rather than "recently deleted answers" ;)

Comment: You have 9 deleted answers on Programmers. 7 of those were deleted when the question was deleted, one you deleted yourself and the more recent one was deleted by the community. Here's the link to the question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/212522/how-to-indicate-that-a-class-might-implement-an-interface.

Comment: @YannisRizos could you write it as an answer, please. Thank you. I simply have lost it, that is the thing.

Comment: @Gangnus Sure...

Comment: @Oded I do not agree. The questions on UI of SE sites belong to meta, not to local meta sites. Even more there is a specific tag as per-site-meta for such questions about how to work with meta-sites. The same question could be asked about every SE site and as you take it, it has to be asked 60 times?

Comment: @Gangnus - you have a specific issue regarding Programming. Or at least that is how you phrased the question. If you had phrased it more generally, that's a different issue.

Comment: @Oded I thought about formulation as "SomeSite/MetaSomeSite", but as I know, people will at once start to look for the concrete answer. I wanted to be helpful, for I have many accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 9 deleted answers on Programmers. 7 of those were deleted when the question was deleted, one you deleted yourself and the more recent one was deleted by three community members. I'm guessing that's the one you are looking for, here's the link to the question: [How to indicate that a class might implement an interface?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212522/how-to-indicate-that-a-class-might-implement-an-interface).

As ChrisF already mentioned, you should be able to see your answer now that you have a link to the question. You can also edit and improve it - as is, it's more of a comment than an actual answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you. I found it. As for reasons, I think, it was almost automatic delete of the short text.

Answer (score 2):

You can always see your deleted answers (regardless of your reputation) when viewing the question. So as long as you have (or can find) a link to the question you can then find the the link to the answer.

Of course, only moderators or 10K+ users will be able to see your answer, so it would be best to include the text of the answer in your Meta question.